# Hadoop Process started from Java Code

Tags: java, hadoop

I am currently trying to start an Apache Hadoop job inside my Java Code. Before I jump into my question, I would like to provide some information about my code and my working environment.

Since I am working on a development environment (Ubuntu 14.04, Eclipse Kepler, OpenJDK v7), I have set up Hadoop in a standalone-mode. In detail, I have only made the following changes in my `.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/db2inst1/hadoop

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
```

Therefore, the output from a Terminal I get is the following:

```
db2inst1@rethimno:~$ which hadoop
/home/db2inst1/hadoop/bin/hadoop
db2inst1@rethimno:~$ hadoop version
Hadoop 1.2.1
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152
Compiled by mattf on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
From source with checksum 6923c86528809c4e7e6f493b6b413a9a
This command was run using /home/db2inst1/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
db2inst1@rethimno:~$
```

Turning to my Java Code (I invoke inside Eclipse IDE) is the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;


public class ProcessSpanwer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] command = {"hadoop", "version"};
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        Process p = processBuilder.start();
        p.waitFor();
    }

}
```

As you can understand, the code above is just some sample code to test whether I can initiate a Hadoop Job through Java. The output I receive from the execution is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hadoop": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at ProcessSpanwer.main(ProcessSpanwer.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 1 more
```

It is apparent to me that the JVM does not have access to the environment variables `$HADOOP_INSTALL` and the updated `$PATH` variable. I have verified that by printing out the environment variables through Java code.

Therefore, my question is what do I need to do in order to:

1. Make Hadoop visible by the JVM
2. Provide the Hadoop Classpath (jar libraries) to my Java Code

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try starting your java code from the command line?

Comment: Why don't you directly use the Hadoop Java classes to create the job? There is no need to fork a new process or go to the command line.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut because I need a new Java process spawned from the current Java process.

Comment: @user3679868 I did and it worked. But, how can I configure Eclipse IDE to recognize the `$HADOOP_INSTALL` and updated `$PATH` variables?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut what do you mean by "use the Hadoop Java Classes to create the job"? Can you specify what you mean please.

Comment: Did you restart your Eclipse after setting the environment variables?

Comment: Yes I did. I also tried to set environment variables for my runtime (through Run Configurations Menu of Eclipse) but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bashrc` is the terminal configuration and is user-specific.

It seems that when you run a java program from eclipse, it uses system wide configuration. Therefore the program does not see `Hadoop`. However, your terminal program can see `Hadoop` since the your terminal is configured to see `Hadoop`.

You can either use the full path to the `Hadoop` script like `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop` or make the same updates that you made to `.bashrc` to `/etc/profile` file. This should solve the problem I guess.

This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40708/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-bashrc-bash-profile-gnomer) elaborates the difference between `.bashrc` and `/etc`

PS: you can access environment variables using `System.getenv()` [checkout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) for in detail.

Comment: I figured this out yesterday. Thank you for your answer. I will mark your post as the correct answer. Thank you again.